# getListId() for listItems using the DocumentApp library for Google Apps Script doesn't recognize coherent lists in documents?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps, google-docs-api

Due to the lack of functionality within Google Docs for checklists, I'm writing a code script to automatically calculate the percent completion of a list based on the symbol present of each list item belonging to a list. In order to do this, I am retrieving all listItems relevant to a listID, and then attempting to check their GLYPH_TYPE attribute in order to differentiate which items have been completed (which the user indicates by clicking the symbol left of the list item and changing it to a checkmark). The issue is, when attempting to get all list items that belong to a given listID, the ID is different when the symbol in front of the list item is changed (in other words, the GLYPH_TYPE attribute is different.)

Despite the list being coherent to the user, (the list simply looks like a checklist with some items complete and others not,) I cannot simply identify the list in the code with the getListID() method due to the embedded Google functionality that automatically identifies a different list when the  GLYPH_TYPE attribute is different from the other listItems.

Below is the method I am using to attempt to get all listItems which belong to a specific listID, and then returning the corresponding listItems in an array for statistical analysis:

```
function getAllListItemsInList(listID,documentID){
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentID);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var listItems = body.getListItems();
  var listItemsWithID = [];
  for(var i = 0; i< listItems.length; i++){
    Logger.log(listItems[i].getListId());
    if(listItems[i].getListId() == listID){
      listItemsWithID.push(listItems[i]);
    }
  }
  return listItemsWithID;
}
```

If you run this method on a coherent list of 5 listItems in which one has a checkmark as the glyph type instead of a bulletpoint, the following is logged and returned;

The following is logged and returned;

```
[19-01-22 15:44:04:885 MST] kix.jbwvso8omgk3
[19-01-22 15:44:04:886 MST] kix.jbwvso8omgk3
[19-01-22 15:44:04:886 MST] kix.mvpj0m62r3h8
[19-01-22 15:44:04:887 MST] kix.jbwvso8omgk3
[19-01-22 15:44:04:888 MST] kix.jbwvso8omgk3
[19-01-22 15:44:04:888 MST] [ListItem, ListItem, ListItem, ListItem]
```

As you can see, only 4 items are returned instead of 5. 4 of the 5 listItems have the same listID, the one that has a different glyph type does not.

Is there an intuitive workaround? Or possibly a more intuitive way to track the completion of "checklists" in Google Docs?

Comment: Have you tried other Javascript method like `.map()` or `.fill()`?

Comment: For example, as a workaround, how about comparing the document with and without modifying? From ``the list being coherent to the user``, it is considered that the length of ``getListItems()`` is the same before and after the modification. I think that this can be used for the result you want. And I think that the goal might be able to be achieved by comparing the list IDs. If I misunderstand your situation, I apologize.

Comment: This is a reasonable solution for calculating the percent completion of the list; however, in order to even group a list together, I need to identify it in the code first. After that point, I can then use the GLYPH_TYPE attribute to calculate percent completion. Your solution would work if I am forced to write a function which identifies a coherent list in the code without using the unreliable listIDs, but I am trying to avoid this, as it would be unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: @Jaden Ranzenberger I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. By the way, I cannot understand what you want about ``I need to identify it in the code first.``. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Sure; so, what I am trying to do essentially is getting all list items that belong to a list in the code as an array. This can be done with the function getListItems(), a DocumentApp function, and then grouping all list items which have the same listID into an array. That is what my function getAllListItemsInList() in the original post is attempting to do. The only problem is, even though a list is obviously coherent when viewing it in a google doc, changing the glyph in front of the listItem from a bulletpoint to a different glyph changes that list Item's list ID, making my method useless.

Comment: So I need to find a reliable way to get all list Items that belong to a list in an array in the code. That is what I meant by that statement. @Tanaike

Comment: @Jaden Ranzenberger Thank you for providing the detail information. From your reply, I thought that the index of array which has the list items might be able to be used for your situation. The index is the same before and after the user's editing. Does this become a workaround?